# list index out of range in simple Python script

Tags: python, list

I just started learning Python and want to create a simple script that will read integer numbers from user input and print their sum.

The code that I wrote is

```
inflow = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
result = 1
for i in inflow:
    result += inflow[i]
print(result)
```

It gives me an error

> IndexError: list index out of range

pointing to `result += inflow[i]` line. Can't see what am I doing wrong?

BTW, is there more elegant way to split input flow to the list of integers?

Comment: Should just be `result += i`. Also, why is `result` initialised to 1?

Comment: Regarding elegance, you could reduce your expression for `inflow` to something like `inflow = map(int, input().split())` (or alternatively, `inflow = (int(i) for i in input().split())`. I would also rename it from `inflow` to something like `nums`, as it's not really anything representing a stream or flow, `input()` just reads a line of input into a string.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, thanks, initialised to 1 because of my inattentiveness, obviously should be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also avoid the loop altogether:

```
inflow = '1 2 34 5'
```

Then

```
sum(map(int, inflow.split()))
```

will give the expected value

```
42
```

EDIT:

As you initialize your result with 1 and not 0, you can then also simply do:

```
sum(map(int, input.split()), 1)
```

My answer assumes that the input is always valid. If you want to catch invalid inputs, check [Anton vBR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46625331/1534017).

Comment: I'd rename input though and making the list is not necessary. (Nice edits +1)

Comment: One more thing. Looks like he/she starts with 1, so +1?

Comment: @AntonvBR: True, will edit this as well, although based on the description ('read numbers and print their sum') this seems unnecessary.

Comment: note, `sum` accepts an extra argument `start` that defaults to `0`, but you can just do `sum(seq, 1)` to start summing with `1`

Answer (score 2):

Considering: I just started learning Python

I'd suggest something like this, which handle input errors:

```
inflow = raw_input("Type numbers (e.g. '1 3 5') ") #in py3 input()
#inflow = '1 2 34 5'

try:
    nums = map(int, inflow.split())
    result = sum(nums)
    print(result)

except ValueError:
    print("Not a valid input")
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in list` gives the values of the list, not the index.

```
inflow = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
result = 1
for i in inflow:
    result += i
print(result)
```

If you wanted the index and not the value:

```
inflow = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
result = 1
for i in range(len(inflow)):
    result += inflow[i]
print(result)
```

And finally, if you wanted both:

```
for index, value in enumerate(inflow):
```

Answer (score 1):

> script that will read integer numbers from user input and print their
>   sum.

try this :

```
inflow = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
result = 0
for i in inflow:
    result += i
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were going to index the list object you would do:

```
for i in range(len(inflow)):
    result += inflow[i]
```

However, you are already mapping `int` and turning the `map` object into a `list` so thus you can just iterate over it and add up its elements:

```
for i in inflow:
    result += i
```

As to your second question, since you arent doing any type testing upon cast (i.e. what happens if a user supplies `3.14159`; in that case `int()` on a `str` that represents a `float` throws a `ValueError`), you can wrap it all up like so:

```
inflow = [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')] # input() returns `str` so just cast `int`
result = 1
for i in inflow:
    result += i
print(result)
```

To be safe and ensure inputs are valid, I'd add a function to test type casting before building the list with the aforementioned list comprehension:

```
def typ(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return True  # cast worked
    except ValueError:
        return False  # invalid cast

inflow = [x for x in input().split(' ') in typ(x)] 
result = 1
for i in inflow:
    result += i
print(result)
```

So if a user supplies `'1 2 3 4.5 5 6.3 7'`, `inflow = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]`.

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing, in chronological order, is this:

1. Gather user input, split per space and convert to integer, and lastly store in `inflow`
2. Initialize `result` to 1
3. Iterate over every item in `inflow` and set item to `i`
4. Add the current item, `i` to `result` and continue
5. After loop is done, print the result total.

The broken logic would be at *step 4*.

To answer your question, the problem is that you're not gathering the index from the list as expected-- you're iterating over each *value* in the list opposed to the index, so it's really undefined behavior based on what the user inputs. Though of course, it isn't what you want.

What you'd want to do is:

```
inflow = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
result = 1
for i in range(len(inflow)):
    result += inflow[i]
print(result)
```

And on your last regard; there are two real ways to do it, one being the way you're doing right now using list, map  and:

```
inflow = [int(v) for v in input().split()]
```

IMO the latter looks better. Also a suggestion; you could call stdlib function `sum(<iterable>)` over a list of integers or floats and it'll add each number and return the summation, which would appear more clean over a `for` loop.

Note: if you're splitting per whitespace you can just call the `str.split()` function without any parameters, as it'll split at every whitespace regardless.

```
>>> "hello world!".split()
['hello', 'world!']
```

Note: also if you want extra verification you could add a bit more logic to the list comprehension:

```
inflow = [int(v) for v in input().split() if v.isdigit()]
```

Which checks whether the user inputted valid data, and if not, skip past the data and check the following.